# How to set the python type hinting for a dictionary variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, types

Let say I have a dictionary:

```
from typing import Dict

v = { 'height': 5, 'width': 14, 'depth': 3 }

result = do_something(v)

def do_something(value: Dict[???]):
    # do stuff
```

How do I declare the dictionary type in `do_something`?

Comment: IIUC, see [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#built-in-types)

Comment: I believe it's `Dict[key_type, value_type]`, so in your case `Dict[str, int]`

Comment: TypedDict, check [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`Dict` takes two "arguments", the type of its keys and the type of its values. For a `dict` that maps strings to integers, use

```
def do_something(value: Dict[str, int]):
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) could probably be a little more explicit, though.

Comment: Thanks, Chepner, but what would I do if the dictionary also had a key such as 'name': 'Book', i.e. a string key, and string value including the original values?

Comment: Then you would have to use a union type that could cover a string or an int.  `Dict[str, Union[str, int]]`.

Comment: I'm on python 3.7 and I was struggling with below type hint until I saw this post and realized that I need to use 'Dict' instead of 'dict':                                                                   ~ErrorClass = Literal["Info", "Warning", "Error"]                                                                       Score = Dict[ErrorClass, float]~

Comment: how do i write typing if have multiple keys and values, with keys and values of different types for a dict like: `{'a':1, b'abc':[1.0,2.0,3.0],23:['x','y','z']}`.types are :"{str:int, bytes-string:list(floats), int: list(str)}"

Comment: `dict`/`Dict` can't handle that case. You would need to use [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) (which itself is limited to dicts with `str` keys but arbitrary types for each value).

Comment: @soumeng78 If you haven't noticed yet (and can take advantage), Python 3.9 makes `dict` generic, so `dict[ErrorClass, float]` would now work. `Dict` is now deprecated (though I have no idea if there is a timeline for actually removing it).

Comment: Minor nitpick: the [docs for typing.Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) recommend using `Mapping[]` for arguments and `Dict[]` for return types, so `Mapping[str, int]` might be even more appropriate here.

Comment: That makes sense: broad arguments and narrow return types work better with sub typing.

Answer (score 63):

### Python 3.9 on:

Use lowercase `dict` in the same method as the accepted answer.  [`typing.Dict` and similar upper case generic types which mirror built-ins are deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) due to [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/):

```py
def my_func(value: dict[str, int]):
    pass
```

Comment: This is great. `Dict` and `List` are ugly and remind me of Java.

Comment: @BurgerBurglar I WISH more of python reminded me of Java... :D Changing the case of a reference class to lower case because it is prettier rather than referencing the class that defines the type you wish to type hint seems like a step backwards.

Comment: @topher217 'dict' and 'list' are actually the class names. I believe that's to distinguish built-ins from non-built-ins as apposed to primitive vs non primitive. User-defined types are typically pascal case. Python likely derived this naming scheme from C or C++. In C structs are typically lower case (though there are a lot of people that use pascal case), and in C++ people typically use pascal, but all standard library types are lowercase.

Comment: @HunterKohler huh. So they [are](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr). I see. Thanks for clarifying. I should have read through the PEP 585 before commenting.

Comment: @topher217 Not having to type `from typing import Dict` is also quite nice in 3.9+.