# How can I initialize an empty Python dictionary and set types for the keys and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to declare an empty dictionary, *not* as an argument to a function, that will only allow specific data types to be used as keys and values.

This may seem similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593803/how-to-set-the-python-type-hinting-for-a-dictionary-variable), but that question is about declaring the dictionary type as an argument to a function. `value: dict[str, int]` doesn't work when declaring a dictionary as a standalone object.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
my_var: int = 4
my_str_var: str = "Hello"
```

But when initializing a dictionary. Something like:

```
my_dict: {key = str, value = int} ## totally wrong, but hopefully gets the idea across.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `my_dict: dict[str, int] = {}`

Comment: "that will only allow specific data types to be used as keys and values. " python dictionaries never work like this, you can use annotations but they don't have a runtime effect

Comment: Okay, so I guess I'll have to type-check as I go along. Thanks for clearing that up! I knew there must be a reason why no one talked about this type of thing. :)

Comment: If you want a dictionary which will produce runtime errors when given the wrong types, you need to implement such a subclass yourself (or use some packages which already do so). But that is a rather unpythonic thing to do.

Comment: @no-one no, you don't have to do that either.

Comment: @deceze perhaps it is a use-case for a slotted class, to handle the strict naming